# OutOfMemoryError error while rotating a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, out-of-memory, exif

**Goal:** I want to send the captured image file to server, in code I can send `photoFile` to server using retrofit, but the image is rotated on server side, so my goal is to observe rotation, rotate back to real state and post that file to server.

**Issue**: I capture image from cam and then observe its rotation and based on that I try to rotate it back, but it gives out of memory error while creating second rotated bitmap.

**Question:** I am looking for solution where I can rotate and send it to server without creating bitmap, if not, avoiding outofmemory error and send correctly rotated file to server.

```
       else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath(), new BitmapFactory.Options());
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            //getRotation method rightly gives 90 as rotation.
            matrix.postRotate(getRotation(exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 
                                  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)));

            //point of outofmemory error while creating this bitmap
            Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: ");
        }
```

Comment: You dont need to create a bitmap. You set the right rotation in the file with ExifInterface. Read the exif in. Set rotation as wanted. Write exif back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it gives out of memory error while creating second rotated bitmap

You may not have free system RAM to load in a single full-resolution photo, let alone two of them. Your primary choices are:

- Do not load a full-resolution photo. Instead, choose a smaller resolution, using `BitmapFactory.Options` and `inSampleSize` to have Android scale down the image when loading it in. This does not guarantee that it will work, as your heap may be rather fragmented, but it increases the likelihood that it will work.
- Do the rotation on the server, where you have lots of RAM, lots of CPU time, etc.
- Load the photos and do the rotation in C/C++ code, using the Android NDK, as native allocations (e.g., `malloc()`) do not count against your heap limit.
- Use `android:largeHeap="true"` in the manifest for your `<application>`. On some devices, this will give you a larger heap to work with. There is no guarantee that you will get a larger heap, and even with the larger heap you may still run out of memory.

> I am looking for solution where I can rotate and send it to server without creating bitmap

There is nothing in Android for that, sorry.

Comment: is it possible to clear `bitmapOrg` before creating `rotatedBitamp` so I get little more space to work with ?

Comment: @AalapPatel: No, because then you have nothing to rotate.

Comment: tried 1st idea with inSamplesize 2 and it seems to be working, I still have to create bitmap and then file and then post that file to server, I dont think there is another way of sending rotated file with out creating bitmap..

Comment: 2nd Idea doesnt seem to be in my hand, 3rd one is it good idea to use NDK in the project just for one task ?, and 4th one anyways is not guaranteed solution so could not go with that..

Comment: @AalapPatel: "4th one anyways is not guaranteed solution so could not go with that" -- neither is the one that you chose. The second and third ones are the only options that offer any sort of guarantee. "is it good idea to use NDK in the project just for one task ?" -- if you determine that it is the best solution, then yes.

Comment: Why the first one is not guaranteed ? I use it in galaxy s7 edge and it generates more memory images than others..

Comment: @AalapPatel: Reducing the resolution makes it more likely that you will successfully load two of them, but there is no guarantee of this. The amount of heap space that you start with varies *dramatically* by device. You use some of that heap space elsewhere in your app (e.g., UI). And Android's garbage collector does not compact the heap while your app is in the foreground (prior to Android 8.0), meaning that while you may have enough free memory in the aggregate, you do not have a single big enough block of free memory for loading in your smaller-resolution photo.

Comment: @AalapPatel: To draw an analogy: you are complaining that when you try pouring water into a bucket, the bucket overflows. The solution that you are trying is to pour only 1/4th as much water, and that happens to work for the bucket that you are testing. However, there are ~2 billion buckets, from ~10,000 different bucket models, in all shapes and sizes. Sometimes, the buckets will be small, or already have a lot of water in them. In those cases, even pouring in 1/4th the water may be too much, and the bucket may overflow.

Comment: Understood, so for perfect solution, just send file to server and let server guys handle rotation or use NDK in the project,.. ?

Comment: @AalapPatel: Those two are guaranteed to work (in the analogy, you are not using buckets anymore). I would recommend the server approach, as spending CPU and battery on the client does not make the user very happy.

Comment: I wonder how whatsapp and etc deal with this if they deal at client side, it is the issue with cam captured image in android, it is always 90 degrees rotated.. if I wanna do it by my self here then at the end I will have to use my custom cam using camera2 API and then capture image and send..

Answer (score -1):

I know you have to rotate sometime bitmap so here is the helper i use in most of my project , let me know if it solves your problem:

```
public static Bitmap getRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float degree) {
        Bitmap bitmap = bm;
        if (degree != 0) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.preRotate(degree);
//            if(shouldFlip)
//                matrix.preScale(-1,1);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                    bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am doing and it gives error on rotated bitmap creation of outofmemory error